# overloading I'm having two errors

Tags: c#

I having two errors for this. I'm sure where to go from here. Here are the two errors: No overload for method 'bark' takes 3 argument, Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected..Here what the outcome should look like: int=2, double=3.4, string= Frido, Hit any key to close

```
          using System;
          using System.Collections.Generic;
          using System.Linq;
          using System.Text;
          namespace Assignment07
         {
           class Dog
       {
           public void bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dog is barking");
    }

    public void bark(int myInt, double myDouble, string myString) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int=2");
        Console.WriteLine("double=3.4") ;
        Console.WriteLine("string=Fido");        
 {   

        }
     }
         class Program
{
             static void Main(string[] args) 
            { Dog fido = new Dog(); fido.bark(2, 3.4, "Fido"); 
             Console.Write("Hit any key to close"); Console.ReadKey(true); }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why two `Main()` methods? Anyway... you get an error in the second one because your `Dog` class only has one overload for the `bark()` method, and that overload doesn't have any parameters. So when you try to call `bark()` with the arguments `2`, `3.4`, and `"Fido"`, the compiler can't find an overload matching that argument list (because it doesn't exist!).

Comment: If you post code, try to format it in a way that makes it readable for others. In Visual Studio the key-combination Ctrl-E-D reformats your code automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You've got two `Main` methods when there should be one. The reason you're getting the `overload` error is because your `bark` method takes no parameters (`public void bark()`) yet here you're trying to pass three parameters `fido.bark(2, 3.4, "Fido");`. You'd need to create an overloaded `bark` method that has three parameters, e.g.

```
public void bark()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Dog is barking");
}

public void bark(int myInt, double myDouble, string myString) 
{
    //whatever you'd like this method to do
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it! what is the difference between your two "bark" methods and the methods in question? they looks identical to me.

Comment: OP edited the question with my answer for some reason. If you check the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26642145/revisions), you'll see what the original question looked like :)

Comment: Oh...Ok..that is confusing. people shouldn't do that!